# Wireshark- Follow TCP Stream

Tags: windows, tcp, wireshark, packet-capture

How to invoke the GUI option of **follow tcp stream** using command line on Windows?
I've read that there is something like `tcpflow` but on using it, Wireshark says command not found.

The OS I am using is windows and I want to capture and save an HTTP stream.

Comment: Off topic for SO. Not sure what you're looking for even exists.

Comment: I got it all right, and there is no evidence above to the contrary. Your rudeness isn't called for.

Comment: @EJP check the answer, never say it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **dumpcap.exe** which should be in the same folder with **wireshark.exe**

1. dumpcap.exe -D
   This command used to get your interface index list
2. dumpcap.exe -f "tcp port 80" -w YOUR_OUT_PUT_FILE -i YOUR_INTERFACE_INDEX

   This command used to dump the packet.
   And you may got multiple tcp screams with this command. I think this is its limitation.